# IdentityServer WithCustomUserService on External Login throws nullreference exception

Tags: identityserver3

I Implementd a custom userservice to store user data in a database.

Since that I get a NullReferenceException when I try to authenticace with an external provider like facebook.

I can see this stack in the exception which indicates that a value is missing for the loginpage. As A result after clicking on the facebook button i'm standing again at the starting login page.

[image]

But I don't know why or which value exactly

I can see that at the end of AuthenticateExternal `context.AuthenticateResult.User.Claims` contains these claims

[image]

my user service looks simplified like this

```
 public override async Task AuthenticateExternalAsync(ExternalAuthenticationContext context)
{
     string id = context.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Type == "id").Value;

                var user = await gateway.ByExternalIds(context.ExternalIdentity.Provider, id);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    string displayName = context.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Type.Equals("urn:facebook:name")).Value;

                    user = new User(context.ExternalIdentity);

                    await gateway.StoreAsync(user);
                }

                if (user != null)

                {
                    await gateway.SetLastLogin(user.Subject, DateTimeOffset.Now);

                    context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(user.Subject, GetDisplayName(user), identityProvider: context.ExternalIdentity.Provider);
                }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. This behavior occurs when the method for detemerning if the user ist active returns false.

```
Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
```

its little unexpected as I  had expected that in this case i would see something like "unknown user" or "inactive user"